# Google webfonts render invisible on page-load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webfonts, google-webfonts

[image]I'm quite baffled by this and not sure how to show an example.

Using Bootstrap for my website.
Loading Google Web-Font, like I've done multiple times in the past and never had an issue.

For some reason, H1 and H2 are invisible until I highlight them with the mouse, or scroll all the way to the bottom of the page and then back up. Sometimes on page load I can see little bits and pieces of the font, like the bottom of a couple letters, etc.

Or, if I open inspect panel and toggle ANYTHING related to the font... like size, color, etc.. they'll show up.

This is only happening in Chrome.

Any suggestions? Never seen this before.

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/h9qULzjXKVw and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692 may help you.

Comment: Thank you @Ravimallya. It appears it's a slightly different issue unless I missed something. Those issues seem to be related to a default font substituting the google web font, whereas mine aren't showing up at all... or if they do show up, it's fragmented bits and pieces at the bottom of the font.. Very confusing.

Comment: can we have a live example of the page? so we may check it further.

Comment: Has any more light been shed on this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more of a "Don't understand it but glad I figured it out" situation. The content pane which was prior to the content area that I was having trouble with was using the webfont in some links. I had the font-size set to 18px for those links. Changing the font size to 21px or 14px, and several other sizes solved the problem.

I DO NOT understand why... Perhaps the web-font isn't compatible with 18px size? Yet I've never run into this... it makes zero sense. Maybe someone can still shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I am also encountering this. I was able to "fix the glitch" by using JavaScript to change any CSS property on the afflicted elements once the page had finished loading.

An example using jQuery:

```
$(window).on('load', function() { $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').css('zoom',1); });
```